# how do you open a program (notepad) with Expect?

Tags: expect, notepad

How do you use Expect to start a program? I want to have Expect open notepad at the end of my script. How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
exec {*}[auto_execok notepad] $filename &
```

[tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/765)

Comment: in my script, I receive input from an outside source. then, I type "example.log" to the command line, and the input received is printed into a notepad document. how can I do this automatically?